# YouTube Video Management

Tags: youtube-api

I want to build an efficient way to manage our YT channel (600+ videos).
I'm playing with the YT API to retrieve data, using this page:
http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html#Response

Problem is it doesn't seem to give me TAGS (keywords), STATUS (unlisted/private/public) and ANNOTATIONS.

So far I've managed to get the XML file into Excel and start playing with Pivot Tables, but if someone can help me get this data, or point me towards third-party tools that can help manage a large YouTube channel, that would be great.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Keywords are [no longer available in public responses](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html). If you need to retrieve the keywords for videos in your account, you must a [properly authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication) with credentials of the account that owns the videos.

Only public videos are returned in public responses (not surprisingly). The same sort of authorized request will return private and unlisted videos.

Annotations are not exposed anywhere via the Data API.

When you make your authorized request for a feed of videos, be sure that you request the [uploads feed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos) for the user "default" instead of doing a search and using the author=ACCOUNT parameter, and that [won't give you the info you want](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html).

Comment: That's very helpful! I need to work with our software engineers on this to design an interface to manage our data the way we need. For now could you help me find how to get the video status? Even with an authorised request I get no info about this in the resulting XML.